# Django - Annotate field

Tags: django, django-orm

I have 3 models:

1.

```
class Calendar(models.Model):
    ...
    supplier = models.CharField(...)
    subassort = models.CharField(..., null=True)
```

Data example:

```
supplier  | subassort
----------------------
12345     | subassort1
67890     | subassort2
```

2. 

```
class SupplierProductAssortments(models.Model):
    subassort = models.CharField(...)
    supplier = models.CharField(...)
    ui2_code = models.CharField(...)
```

Data example:

```
supplier  | subassort  | ui2_code
---------------------------------
12345     | subassort1 | ui-1
12345     | subassort1 | ui-2
67890     | subassort2 | ui-3
```

3. 

```
class UI2(models.Model):    
    code = models.CharField(...)
    name = models.CharField(...)
```

Data example:

```
code | name
-------------
ui-1 | milk
ui-2 | cheese
ui-3 | meat
```

I need to annotate `ui2` field to queryset of `Calendar`. For better understanding below I wrote a function that demonstrates it:

```
def get_calendars_with_ui2s():
    calendars = Calendar.objects.all()  # need to annotate ui2 names

    for calendar in calendars:
        if subassort := calendar.subassort:
            ui2_codes = SupplierProductAssortments.objects\
                .filter(supplier=calendar.supplier, subassort=subassort)\
                .values_list('ui2_code', flat=True)
            ui2 = UI2.objects.filter(code__in=ui2_codes).values_list('name', flat=True)
        else:
            ui2 = []
        
        calendar.ui2 = ui2

    return calendars
```

Expected output:

```
supplier  | subassort  | ui2
---------------------------------------
12345     | subassort1 | [milk, cheese] 
67890     | subassort2 | [meat]
```

If when filtering `ui2_codes` was by one field I guess it could be solved by `OuterRef`. But there are filtering by two fields.

How can I annotate field `ui2`?

P.S. No FK

Comment: Is `subassort+supplier`  a unique combination in `SupplierProductAssortments`? What should be in result if `subassort = null` in `Calendar`? Are there `Calendar` records which have no links to `SupplierProductAssortments`, should they be returned? Please add to your question sample source dataset and expected output of the query.

Comment: Easier in general if you have ForeignKey or other relationship fields between the models. Also likely to be more efficient because the DB *knows* its a relationship.